# Meaning of "asymptotic distribution" of estimator in Generalized Linear Models.

Tags: statistics, asymptotics, distribution-theory

We have a generalized linear model. Then maximum-likelihood estimator of parameters has asymptotic distribution $N(\beta, J^{-1})$:
$$\hat \beta \rightarrow_d N(\beta, J^{-1}),$$

- $\beta$ - true parameters (we know them in some cases, e.g. when doing simulations)
- $J$ - Fisher information matrix $J = X^T S X$, where $X$ is plan matrix of size $n \times p$ and $S$ is something (assume we know how to calculate this term).

Say, that we do simulations and given fixed $X$ (we could subset $X$ to use more or less rows though) we generate $k$ times new $Y$ and based on that we estimate $\hat \beta$. **I am not sure if I understand correctly what is asymptotic distribution here.** It's either:

a. incresing number of observations (taking larger subsets of $X$ rows) guarantees that empirical $\hat \beta$ covariance matrix is closer and closer to $J^{-1}$ or

b. repeating experiment more times (this time $k$ gets bigger) guarantees that averaged empirical covariance matrix of $\hat \beta$ gets closer and closer to $J^{-1}$.

I suspect that a. is the true answer and (b.) is also somehow true, but with some changed detail and that (b.) is related to CLT theorem while (a.) is not. Could anyone make it clear?

Comment: Cześć! I suppose you meant CLT in your last paragraph. Please edit it so that it is not so difficult to decipher for people who might answer your question.

Comment: I am not fully sure your equation for the limit is correct, c.f., https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/198119/glm-coefficient-estimates-distribution

Comment: @Sergio as far as I know matrix $J$ can be alternatively expressed as minus the expected value of Hessian of likelihood function, so this is the same thing. But it doesn't matter so much actually, I just want to understant what does "asymptotic" mean here

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, it seems you mix two concepts here:

1. Asymptotic properties of estimated parameters;
2. Bootstrap.

The asymptotic distribution is based on the population/sample concept. Let's say you have two random variables $(X, Y)$ (not the data), and the population model is $Y=\alpha + \beta X + \epsilon$. From this population model, you get some samples $(x_1, y_1), (x_2, y_2), \dots, (x_n, y_n)$. You want to estimate the population parameters $\alpha$ and $\beta$ using these samples, say they are $a$ and $b$, or $\hat{\alpha}$ and $\hat{\beta}$. What the asymptomic normality says is that as the sample size $n \rightarrow \infty$, the joint distribution of $a$ and $b$ are converging to a normal distribution. In reality, we only have data. Population is something we assume they exist. From this point of view, (a) is correct.

When you fix data $x$ and generating $k$ sets of data $y$, that's bootstrap. For each set of data $y$, you get an estimate of $\hat{a}$ and $\hat{b}$. In total, you will have $k$ sets of $\hat{a}$ and $\hat{b}$, then you can make inference using these $\hat{a}$s and $\hat{b}s$, e.g. the median, percentile. And hopefully (or proved under certain conditions), the joint distribution of $\hat{a}$ and $\hat{b}$ is converging to that of $a$ and $b$, as $k \rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: What's the distribution of $\hat\beta$ in case of Monte Carlo simulation?

Comment: @Brzoskwinia I made some corrections. It's bootstrap, rather than Monte Carlo. The idea is that the distribution of $\hat{b}$ will converge to that of $b$. I don't know if it has certain confirmed distribution in this case.

Comment: I've read your answer multiple times, but still not sure about it. Do you think that both version of my understanding (a. and b.) are correct? I mean, what is "asymptotic distribution" here, is it asymptotic regarding both $n \rightarrow \infty$ and $k \rightarrow \infty$? If so, why?

Comment: $n \rightarrow \infty$

Comment: The distribution of $a$ and $b$ may not be normal, e.g. sample size is small, the error term follows a exponential distribution. In this case, the distribution of bootstrap estimates $\hat{a}$ and $\hat{b}$ converges to that of $a$ and $b$, which may not be normal.